# Google Places API server key doesn't work using Curl

Tags: ruby, api, curl, google-places-api

I have obtained a valid api key from Google Places API.  I need to use this on the backend, so I get a server-side key.  However, the call does not work using curl nor the Rails console.

It DOES, however, work thru the browser.  That said, I have triple checked that I am using the server-side key that I generated.  I'm also only using the sample URL that is in the Google places documentation, so all params should be correct.  Here is my curl:

curl -v https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=my_key

Also, in (Ruby) Rails console:

Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=my_key"))

Any ideas?  It seems like multiple people have had issues, but there is nothing specific out there for server keys not working.

Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned the response when using curl:  {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CURL, be sure to put quotes around the URL.  Otherwise, if you're working in Linux, the URL will be truncated after the first ampersand, which will cause a REQUEST_DENIED response.

For HTTPS with Ruby, the following should work (ref http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html):

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=...")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
print response.body
```

Comment: That was it.  Had no idea quotes vs non-quotes was a difference, but lesson learned.  Thanks!